# Is there a way to prevent a CSS Transition ending prematurely?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have a transition set on an styled `button`, which is getting triggered on `:active` state. So it smoothly goes to a *pressed* state, then smoothly goes back to *normal* state.

My problem is that the transition animation seems to end prematurely, meaning even if `transition-duration` is 2s, it will last much shorter, especially on mobile device taps.

Meaning the animation works on touchpad taps (relatively long), or holding the button on mobile devices, but I want it to activate and last the full time, on both mouse clicks and mobile taps.

I saw somewhere on the net, that putting the `:active` state on the parent, then translating the child from the parent will fix the issue, but no success yet.

Here a web environment with my code -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-tx57pk?file=src/Button.jsx

And here's the code block itself ⬇️

```js
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

export const Button = styled.button`
   --easing: cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.89, 0.32, 1.28);
   --bg-color: #ddd;
   --shadow-color: grey;
   
   width: 100%;
   height: 5rem;

   color: black;
   outline-offset: 5px;

   border: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;

   display: grid;
   place-items: center;

   font-family: inherit;
   font-weight: 700;

   touch-action: manipulation;

   transition: all 0.5s var(--easing);

   background-color: var(--bg-color);

   border-radius: 15px;

   font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 25px;
   letter-spacing: 1.25px;

   box-shadow: 0px 8px 0px var(--shadow-color);

   &:active {
      transform: translateY(8px);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px var(--shadow-color);
   }
`;
```

Comment: `:active` only applies in the short moment in which you _are_ actually "activating" an element - for example, as long as you have the mouse button pressed down, or when the tab happens. Directly after that, the element is _not_ in the `:active` state any more - so whatever properties you changed in the `:active` state, go back to their old values, _now_. You can't expect a transition with a longer duration that was triggered by the element going _into_ the active state, to still do anything now. Maybe use the `:focus` state instead?

Comment: @CBroe I've tried using `:focus`, the only issue for me is that it doesn't go back to normal until the next tap/click, meaning if a button doesn't navigate to a different page, it will stay pressed. Maybe a combination of `@keyframes` with `:focus` will work? Or should I use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, `:focus` will only "go away" again, when the focus moves to a different element. Might need to use JS for this one then.